After update to Expo SDK 51 - @expo/vector-icons stopped working
I have updated my project to Expo SDK 51 and vector icons stopped working. It doesn't show the icons anymore when I start the project from Expo Go.
I have tried updating babel config as suggested from the web:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true)
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      'transform-inline-environment-variables',
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: {
            '@': './src',
            '^react-native-vector-icons(/.*)?$': '@expo/vector-icons$1',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
    env: {
      production: {
        plugins: ['react-native-paper/babel'],
      },
    },
  }
}


Having the same issue, if I create a brand new app from scratch I can see icons on any platforms.

same issue, have you found a solution?

I Had the same issue upgrading from expo 50 to 51.
Following this github issue https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/4295
Removing yarn.lock / package.lock.json
Removing node_modules
yarn / npm i
This fixed it for me without any babel config changes.

I did like this,
<SymbolView
  name="camera.viewfinder"
  tintColor={color}
  size={18}
  fallback={
    <FontAwesome6 size={16} name="camera" color={color} />
  }
/>

I hope it helps.
